# Stop appending when if rule is no longer true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a project where I need to clone span.response11, append it to a #parent, then add a new div to span.response11. I have the cloning process done but when adding the new div, my IF statement continues to add the div's to elements that already have it appended

Here is a fiddle with my jquery:
https://jsfiddle.net/4bmwbkgx/2/

```
// if this cloned element doesn't already have the child div.red, append it.
$("#parent > span").each(function(index, element) {
  if ($(element).not(":has(.red)")) {
    $(element).prepend('<div class="red">This is red</div>');
  }
});
```

I only want div.red to be added once. If span.response already has div.red as a child, the jquery shouldn't add anymore div's.

How do I get my function to stop adding more div's?

Comment: You are cloning the element that you already appended the red to. Rethink all your logic

Comment: @charlietfl I'm cloning the element, then appending the red. Once cloned, I see there can be an issue of which element to clone when clicking multiple times. I'll have to make adjustments so that span.response inner html is cloned and wrapped with something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If `span.response` already has `div.red` as a child, the jQuery shouldn't add anymore `div`'s.

You shouldn't use `:has`, it is for testing the same element. Use `.find` and check if there's one:

```
$("#parent > span").each(function(index, element) {
  // Do the below, only when `.red` is not there inside this element.
  if (!$(element).find(".red").length) {
    $(element).prepend('<div class="red">This is red</div>');
  }
});
```

Also, on a different note, I would strongly object you from inserting `<div>` inside `<span>`, as `<span>` is an inline element, while `<div>` is a block one!

Comment: `has` is a bit like find , not for same element

Comment: @charlietfl Ah... I get it now, the context differs... `:)` I have added some more info to make my answer better.

Comment: I think the problem is in the cloning actually

Comment: @charlietfl Exactly... `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar thank you for the response! Using .find solved the issue for me. I'll keep in mind that :has is for testing the same element.

Comment: @cgrouge no it is not...but your use was incorrect. Need to check `length` because a jQuery object ... any object...is always truthy

Comment: `:has` is fine, the problem is that `.not()` is the opposite of `.filter()` rather than being the opposite of `.is()`. `$('element').is(':not(:has(.red))')` is kinda silly IMO and can be expressed better from the get-go